# at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

I am facing this exception at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray don't know why? i have use this before in different work didn't get this exception

```
List<NameValuePair> pair = new ArrayList<>();
pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", String.valueOf(getitemno)));
json = JSONParser.makeHttpRequest("http://192.168.1.51:80/StopViewApi/index.php","POST",pair);
Log.d("Route Response", json.toString());
int success = 0;
try {
  success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
  Routearrray = new ArrayList<String>();
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
  if (success == 1) {
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    json = new JSONObject(JSONParser.Result);
    JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("data");
    for (int i = 0; i <= jArray.length(); i++) {
      jsonarray = jArray.getJSONArray(i);
      Stopnames = jsonarray.getString(0);
      Counter++;
      if (Counter <=jArray.length()) {
        //Routearrray.add(Stopnames);
        Log.d("Stop name:", Stopnames);
        //Log.d("Route name:", Routearrray.toString());
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
```

JSON URL

```
{
  "data":[
         "Rawat","Islamabad Mor","Kaak Pull","Lohi Bher","Koral Chowk","Gangal",
         "Khana Bridge","Zia Masjid","Kuri Road","Dhok Kala Khan","Faizabad",
         "Pirwadhai Mor","Tanki Stop I-8\/4","I-8\/3 Stop","Al Shifa Hospital","AIOU",
         "Zero Point","Children Hospital","F-8\/4","Ali Hospital"
  ],
  "success":1,
  "status":200,
  "status_message":"Login Successfull"
}
```

Error: at Line

```
 jsonarray = jArray.getJSONArray(i);
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Are you trying to get jsonarray from jsonarray? You should call .getString(i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your JSON, `jArray` is a array of String and not an array of JSONArray.

Replace:

```
jsonarray = jArray.getJSONArray(i);
Stopnames = jsonarray.getString(0);
```

with:

```
Stopnames = jArray.getString(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

the for loop should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
```

Comment: Sure, but how does that explain the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to parse String values as JSONArray. jArray is an array of Strings, not JSONArrays, so all you need to do is just extract the String values from it.

```
JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("data");
// You already have a JSONArray, now all you need to do is extract String values from it
for (int i = 0; i <= jArray.length(); i++) {
    Log.d("Stopnames: " , jArray.getString(i));
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you "data" is of type json array. whats inside "data" is not a jsonarray, they are just jsonstrings.

change the following lines

```
jsonarray = jArray.getJSONArray(i);
Stopnames = jsonarray.getString(0);
```

to

```
stopnames += jArray.getString(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get jsonarray from jsonarray, while the json array contains json objects. try this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
Stopnames = jsonObject.getString(Integer.toString(i))
```